# Naming constraints using hibernate and JPA 2.2

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, constraints

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.16

We got a 'common' database class which we inherit for our classes. One of the attributes it contains is a 'created' timestamp.

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = DataBaseConstants.CREATED_COLUMNDEFINITION)
private Timestamp created;
```

Because of multiple database implementations we have DatabaseConstants which include code that is different for the different databases (mainly SQLServer & MariaDB). Which might look like this:

```
<CREATED_COLUMNDEFINITION>TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)</CREATED_COLUMNDEFINITION>
```

When I want to update the constaints I have the issue that they have auto-generated names (I do not know where they come from) which makes it very hard to know which constraint is which so I want to name them.

Is there any simple way of doing it which I am missing? Or am I doing the naming strategy in some configuration file we have not set up?

Edit:
"The default clause in column definition is just a shortcut for creating a constraint; default value is not an intrinsic property of a column. If you want to modify default for already existing column, you have to drop the constraint first"

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be a constraint though, it is just a column definition. Do you have an example of a constraint that is auto-generated by hibernate?

Comment: But this actually creates constraints in my SQL-server database, atleast that is what I thought. When I try to change this specific column definition I can only do it by dropping and readding constraints, or am I misunderstanding something?

In the case where this came up I actually wanted to change the column definition of a database without destroying all the data in it. Maybe I am mixing the two things up..

Comment: It creates a column in a table. What your RDBMS does internally is a separate question. A JPA provider simply creates what you tell it to create

Comment: "The default clause in column definition is just a shortcut for creating a constraint; default value is not an intrinsic property of a column. If you want to modify default for already existing column, you have to drop the constraint first"

Comment: For future googlists: 
Something like the duplicated answer would probably have solved the core problem of my issue but we decided to just change the Default value constraints using the SQLExplorer GUI from Microsoft.